# Why do I receive "This value should be of type string" when using a DateTime constraint on Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-validator, symfony5

I have the following entity (only attached the relevant parts):

```php
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(mercure=true)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
 */
class Event {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
    private $createdAt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Its repository:

```
class EventRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository {
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry) {
        parent::__construct($registry, Event::class);
    }
}
```

When creating a POST request to the event endpoint (via Postman or the Swagger UI), it fails with the following exception:

[image: profiler]

Comment: @delboy1978uk I am using Api Platform, it is doing the insertion automatically.

Comment: ```{
 "name": "test",
 "@creator": "/people/23",
 "description": "desc"
}``` though that's quite irrelevant, as the error is at the `createdAt` property which is initialized in the constructor

Comment: I believe the [line throwing the error is here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/05f71d3fd575062be3e5cbd7000a2666f4e1a247/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/DateTimeValidator.php#L37). I wonder if you were to cut out ApiPlatform and create an `Event` yourself and validate it manually, if you would have the issue (it would at least remove complexity). Maybe it's the way ApiPlatform loads the object?

Comment: Hmm, I have another entity (that is not connected to API Platform) that contains a DateTime with the same constraints and that works as expected.

Comment: We're using AP 2.1 and I recall there being something about how it generates objects maybe (it's been a little while)? You can go into the validator file in vendor and `dump()` what it's getting to check, this is where I would start.

Comment: Looking at the line, I see it's checking whether the value is a) scalar or b) an object with a __toString method defined. However, DateTime does not have a __toString method so I think that is the problem. Though, why in my non-API Platform entity it works as expected?

Comment: I am using Symfony 5.0.4

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You are using the wrong of assertion.

`Date` [expects a string or an object that can be cast into a string](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Date.html). And a `DateTimeInterface` is neither.

You should be using a `Type` [constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html).

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type("\DateTimeInterface")
 */
 private $createdAt;
```

The ability to use `Assert\Date` to validate `DateTime` objects was deprecated on Symfony 4.2, and [on Symfony 5.0 it was removed altogether](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/a052378bdd1c94a7a4ddfb826c18215e1a3e0301).

Comment: Ah! We have `@Assert\Type("datetime")` in some places, so that makes sense.

Comment: This was totally new to me! I was ever since using `@Assert\DateTime(groups={"new"})` and now got that weird validator message on my new symfony 5.1 project. Now I changed to the example given above and it works. Awesome! Thank you

Comment: If you need to customize the assertion a bit, here you are an example:  @Assert\Type(type="\DateTimeInterface", message="Custom Message")