# Symfony 6.3 - This value should be of type string

Tags: date, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm developing an application with Symfony 6.3 and I'm encountering a Date problem in a form.

Here is the date definition in my Model :

```
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'date')]
    private $date_of_birth;
```

Here's the field definition in my Type:

```
            ->add('date_of_birth', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(['message' => 'Veuillez sélectionner votre date de naissance.']),
                    new Date(['message' => 'Date de naissance invalide.']),
                ],
            ])
```

And I get this error: This value should be of type string. (In English while my constraint messages are defined in French).

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227679/why-do-i-receive-this-value-should-be-of-type-string-when-using-a-datetime-con), but I'm not using a `DateTime` but a `Date` type, and what's more, I'm not using Assert to validate. Surely I don't understand something.

Comment: You could try to type your $date_of_birth with Date in your entity class like so: private Date $date_of_birth

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the Date constraint on strings (or an object that can be cast into a string). What's more, in this case the DateType type already checks this constraint. You just need to remove this constraint for it to work.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works !

Have a nice day.